# How to Apply Conditional Logic to Where Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, conditional-statements

I can't seem to figure out how to set the logic up for my particular problem. I'm trying to count the number of times the word "Service" appears but only when the RECORD_CODE is INCIDENT. When the RECORD is INCIDENT-UPDATE, it is normally already somewhere else as an INCIDENT so I exclude them to keep from duplicating my data.

However, there are a small number of cases where the SUBMIT_METHOD is "WEB" and the only record is an INCIDENT_UPDATE and I cannot figure out how to look only where the RECORD = 'INCIDENT' unless the particular record has a SUBMIT_METHOD of "WEB" and there is no record for that report # with a RECORD of INCIDENT. It could be a simple problem and I'm just overthinking it but I cannot think of how to do it. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

My query:

```
        SELECT column2, count(*) as 'COUNT'
        from Service.Table
        where date between '1/1/17' and '1/31/17'
        and column1 = 'Issue'
        and RECORD = 'INCIDENT'
        group by column2
```

Sample of the data:

```
REPORT #    RECORD    SUBMIT_METHOD   SUBMIT_DATE   COLUMN2
1234       Incident       Web          1/1/2017     Service
1234    Incident-Update   Web          1/1/2017     Service
1235       Incident      Phone        1/15/2017      Other
1235    Incident-Update  Phone        1/15/2017      Other
1236    Incident-Update   Web         1/18/2017     Service
```

The expected output in this case would be:

```
COLUMN2   COUNT
Service     3
```

If I can provide any other info just let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a `group by` like

```
select column2, count(*)
from tbl1
where SUBMIT_METHOD = 'Web'
group by column2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `not exists` subquery to ensure there is no other row with the same Report# and a record type of INCIDENT:

```
select  *
from    Service.Table t1
where   date between '1/1/17' and '1/31/17' and
        column1 = 'Issue' and
        (
          record = 'Incident' or
          (
            record = 'Incident-Update' and
            submit_method = 'Web' and
            not exist 
            (
              select  *
              from    Service.Table t2
              where   t2.record = 'INCIDENT' 
                      and t2.[Report #] = t1.[Report #]
            )
          )
        )
```

Comment: Thank you very much Andomar! This seems to be on the right track. However, when I run a count(*) grouped by column 2, it only outputs 1 for the service with the incident-update with no other incidents, it does not include the regular incident service counts?

Comment: It should count regular incidents too, as long as the date and column1 conditions match?

Answer (score 0):

```
 ;With cte(REPORT#,RECORD ,SUBMIT_METHOD,SUBMIT_DATE,COLUMN2)
AS
(
SELECT 1234,'Incident'        ,'Web'  , '1/1/2017' ,'Service'   Union all
SELECT 1234,'Incident-Update' ,'Web'  , '1/1/2017' ,'Service'   Union all
SELECT 1235,'Incident'        ,'Phone', '1/15/2017',  'Other'   Union all
SELECT 1235,'Incident-Update' ,'Phone', '1/15/2017',  'Other'   Union all
SELECT 1236,'Incident-Update' ,'Web'  , '1/18/2017', 'Service'
)
SELECT COLUMN2
    ,CountCOLUMN2
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,COUNT(COLUMN2) OVER (
            PARTITION BY COLUMN2 ORDER BY COLUMN2
            ) CountCOLUMN2
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY COLUMN2 ORDER BY COLUMN2
            ) Seq
    FROM cte
    ) Dt
WHERE SUBMIT_DATE BETWEEN '1/1/17'
        AND '1/31/17'
    AND RECORD = 'INCIDENT'
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

OutPut

```
COLUMN2 CountCOLUMN2
--------------------
Service  3
Other    2
```